# Formulate response in excel referencing value in Cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

need a little help with IF & OR to formulate response base on value in Cell M8, I believe i'm very close to what I want but I don't understand the error it.

Ultimately I want the formula to perform the following function

- If Cell M8 = No Access, it will display No Access
- But if M8 have a value above 61, it'll display "Exceeded Pre-Determined Level",
  and if value is between 43 to 61,it'll display "Exceeded Alert Level"

`=IF(M8="No Access","No Access", (ABS(M8)>=61,"Exceeded Pre-Determined Level" OR(ABS(M8)>=43,"Exceeded Alert Level")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
=IF(M8="No Access";M8;
IF(M8>=61;"Ex eed Pre-Determined Level";
IF(AND(M8>43;M8<61);"Exceed Alert Level";
"I guess it Is ok")))
```

You may need to change the `;` to `,`, depending on your formula separator.
Whenever you write complicated Excel formulas, it is always good to write them on a few lines, using <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the formula bar.

Comment: It worked, thanks. I had to change all the ";" to "," though.

Comment: would you be able to help me with another qns I asked ytd too. Which have yet to be answered. 
Is in this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173786/excel-browsing-a-folder-and-automating-data-entry-into-a-default-template"

Thanks in abundance (:

Comment: Could you kindly adapt it to handle negative values?

I have integrated the code to this but is not able to handle negative values.

=IF(M15="No Access", "No Owner",
IF(ABS(M15>F15),"Exceeded Pre-Determined Level",
IF(AND(ABS(M15>E15), ABS(M15<F15)),"Exceeded Alert Level",
" Normal ")))

Comment: @Tyler ABS should be given a value. E.g. `ABS(M15)<ABS(F15)`, in your case if you have `ABS(M15<F15)` then (M15<F15) returns a boolean `True` or `False`.

Comment: Meaning I can't use Abs on M15 to compare with F15?

Comment: @Tyler - meaning you have to know what exactly do you want. E.g. if you want to compare two absolute values, then simply do it like `ABS(M15)<ABS(F15)` and not `ABS(M15<F15)`.

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining

Answer (score 1):

Solution just using another If:

```
=IF(M8="No Access";"No Access";IF(ABS(M8)>=61;"Exceeded Pre-Determined Level";IF(ABS(M8)>=43;"Exceeded Alert Level";"")))
```

In this case you don t need an "Or", "Or" would give you the same result for the 2 different logic tests.

Comment: Hey, thanks. You're right too. But i had to change all of ";" to ","

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you using absolute references in this case as:

(With note that you have tried *absolute numbers*)

```
=IF($M$8="No Access",$M$8,
IF(ABS($M$8)>=61,"Exceeded Pre-Determined Level",
IF(AND(ABS($M$8)>=43,ABS($M$8)<=61), "Exceeded Alert Level",
"None of them")))
```

And your system separating character may `,` or `;`.

Breaking formula with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>